# Perl Crypt-Eksblowfish Cypher encrypted string and must be decrypted in python

Tags: python, perl, encryption, bcrypt, blowfish

A Perl script use this module to encrypt string
http://search.cpan.org/~zefram/Crypt-Eksblowfish-0.009/lib/Crypt/Eksblowfish.pm

I need to code the decrypt fonction in python . I know the key and the salt . 
I tried to use py-bcrypt but it seems that the two equiv function

$ciphertext = $cipher->encrypt($plaintext);
$plaintext = $cipher->decrypt($ciphertext);

are not implemented .

How can i do ? Is there a python module anywhere that can help me to decrypt my strings ?

Comment: Figured out the last piece of the puzzle and updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Update: The complete answer is the Perl code:

```
my $cipher = Crypt::EksBlowFish->new($cost, $salt, $key);
```

is equivalent to this Python code:

```
bf = Eksblowfish()
bf.expandkey(salt, key)
for i in xrange(cost << 1):
  bf.expandkey(0, key)
  bf.expandkey(0, salt)
```

See this repo for example code: https://github.com/erantapaa/python-bcrypt-tests

Original answer:

A partial answer...

I'm assuming you are calling this Perl code like this:

```
use Crypt::EksBlowfish;

my $cipher = Crypt::EksBlowFish->new($cost, $salt, $key);
$encoded = $cipher->encrypt("some plaintext");
```

The `new` method is implemented by the C function `setup_eksblowfish_ks()` in lib/Crypt/EksBlowfish.xs. This looks like it is the same as the `expandKey` method in the Python code [(link)](https://github.com/fwenzel/python-bcrypt/blob/master/bcrypt/eksblowfish.py)

The main difference is the `$cost` parameter which is not present in the Python method. In the Perl code the `$cost` parameter controls how many times this loop is executed after the key schedule has been set up:

```
    for(count = 1U << cost; count--; ) {
            for(j = 0; j != 2; j++) {
                    merge_key(j == 0 ? expanded_key : expanded_salt, ks);
                    munge_subkeys(ks);
            }
    }
```

The Perl `->encrypt()` method enciphers a 64-bit word. The equivalent Python code is:

```
bf.cipher(xl, xr, bf.ENCRYPT)
```

where xl and xr are integers representing the left 32-bits and right 32-bits respectively.

So the recipe should go something like this:

1. Create the Python object: `bf = EksBlowfish()`
2. Initialize the key schedule: `bf.expandkey(salt, key)`
3. Further munge the key schedule using the cost parameter (TBD)
4. Encrypt with `bf.cipher(xl, xr, bf.ENCRYPT)`

Comment: Hi , Thank you for the recipe . I 'm going to try to cook it. I come back to you with results or ..perhaps one more question . But it sounds good. Your help is very appriciated .

Comment: It turns out that `bcrypt.hashpw()` from the package python-bcrypt-0.3.1 may be what you are looking for.